# I want to plot for a range of values in my function in R

Tags: r, function, plot, statistics

I have a function in R that has 3 arguments: a,b,c. The arguents b and c don't change but I want to evaluate the function for a range of values of a, meaning I want a to be 10-1000. I then want to take these values and plot them in R.

Any idea how I can do this?

Comment: Many operations in R are vectorised. What exactly are you trying to do? You should share your code attempt. In its current form, your question is too broad and missing details. I recommend reviewing [how to ask questions here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Then edit your post accordingly.

Comment: The code isn't relevant because it is a funtion I compiled in C and ran through R. So the function lines I have in R are myfunction(a,b,c) where I can choose any value for a,b,c. Let's say I want to plot the results of myfunction(14,3,2) and myunction(22,3,2) and myfunction(100,3,2).... etc. So the arguments b and c stay fixed while I just change the first argument. Each time I run myfunction, it outputs a single number, hence why I want to plot the results when changing argument A

Comment: Yes the code is relevant! As I said, many functions in R are vectorised and there are many ways to skin a cat in R. As I explained, this post is too broad and lacking a clear & workable problem statement.  Regarding plotting: There are many *many* tutorials available that show you how to plot (in base R, `ggplot2`, interactive plots etc.). What have you tried/found out so far? Please share. That will help us understand what specifically you're trying to do. Otherwise this will become a guessing game.

Comment: The code is certainly relevant. Nobody here has any idea what you're looking at otherwise. I wouldn't ask someone to help me edit an essay that I don't show them; likewise we can't help adapt code that we know nothing about

Answer (score 2):

If your function is already vectorized (i.e. will take a vector of `a` values)  then

```r
curve(myfunction(a = x, b = 3, c = 2), from = 10, to 1000)
```

would work. If not, you could do

```r
vc <- Vectorize(myfunction)
curve(vc(a = x, b = 3, c = 2), from = 10, to 1000)
```

`curve()` also has an `n` argument that determines the numbers of points to evaluate in the range (the default is 101).